# Where does CPU store instruction after decoding?

Tags: cpu, register

Control unit in CPU decodes the instruction held in IR (Instruction Register) but where does, if anywhere, CPU store instruction after it has been decoded?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Where does, if anywhere, CPU store instruction after it has been decoded?

Nowhere?

> In simple processors each instruction to be executed is **loaded into the instruction register which holds it while it is decoded, prepared and ultimately executed**, which can take several steps.

<sup>(emphasis mine)</sup>

Source [Instruction register - Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Instruction_register)

> Each computer's CPU can have different cycles based on different
>   instruction sets, but will be similar to the following cycle:
>
> - Fetch the instruction: The next instruction is fetched from the memory address that is currently stored in the program counter and
>     stored into the instruction register. At the end of the fetch
>     operation, the PC points to the next instruction that will be read at
>     the next cycle.
> - Decode the instruction: During this cycle the encoded instruction present in the instruction register is interpreted by the decoder.
> - Read the effective address: In the case of a memory instruction (direct or indirect) the execution phase will be during the next clock
>     pulse. If the instruction has an indirect address, the effective
>     address is read from main memory, and any required data is fetched
>     from main memory to be processed and then placed into data registers
>     (clock pulse: T3). If the instruction is direct, nothing is done
>     during this clock pulse. If this is an I/O instruction or a register
>     instruction, the operation is performed during the clock pulse.
> - Execute the instruction: The control unit of the CPU passes the decoded information as a sequence of control signals to the relevant
>     function units of the CPU to perform the actions required by the
>     instruction such as reading values from registers, passing them to the
>     ALU to perform mathematical or logic functions on them, and writing
>     the result back to a register. If the ALU is involved, it sends a
>     condition signal back to the CU. The result generated by the operation
>     is stored in the main memory or sent to an output device. Based on the
>     feedback from the ALU, the PC may be updated to a different address
>     from which the next instruction will be fetched.
>
> The cycle is then repeated.

Source  [Instruction cycle - Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Instruction_cycle)